# Can't delete items from Trash

Tags: macos, osx-lion, trash

There are some locked files in my trash that I removed from an external hard drive. I have tried a few different things but I delete them.

I have tried:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash
mkdir ~/.Trash
killall Finder
```

and a couple of different programs, but nothing gets rid of the files.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in, or restarting the machine? Also note that the files removed from an external drive are on the Trash folder *on the drive itself*.

Comment: hi, i tried restarting etc but as soon as the drive booted they appear again. How would i empty the trash folder on a drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files weren't stored on your Mac, they won't land in

> `/Users/username/.Trash`

… but instead on the drive itself, which is accessible here:

> `/Volumes/volume-name/.Trashes/501/`

The number `501` is the default user ID of your Mac OS X user account. You can try to manually `rm` the files from there.

For example:

> `cd '/Volumes/La Cie/.Trashes/501'`  *← this will go to the Trash on your external drive*
>   `ls`  *← this will list all files in the Trash*
>   `rm some-file` *← this will remove the file named `some-file` from the Trash*

If that fails, the problem is that the files aren't owned by your user account. Therefore you can try to prefix `rm` with `sudo`, which will try removing the file with root permissions.

Comment: i know this probably makes me a bit stupid but what is the code i would use to do this? Its an external hard drive calle La Cie..

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were aware of the terminal commands. You can use `cd '/Volumes/La Cie/.Trashes/501/'` to get there and then try to list the files with `ls`. Remove a file by typing `rm name-of-file`. Report back if you have any issues!

Comment: thank you, got in to the directory ok however each of the items is a folder that contains another folder and then another and then two locked files. They are about 27 in total. Is there a quicker way that doesn't involve going in to all of the folders?

Comment: just as an addition i tried going in to the folders and got this:

Comment: override rw-r--r--  root/wheel uchg for Bootx? - when i tried to delete

Comment: I added sudo before and it worked. seems like the files were strangely linked so only had to delete a few and then all went. thank you very much

Comment: Ah, that's what I would have suggested next. In that case, files were owned by `root` and you didn't have the permissions to remove them all along. `sudo rm` is the way to go here.